# Triangulation 3d - normals

Tags: algorithm, normalization, triangulation, wavefront

Let's say that I got an Obj file which contains this line:

> f 3963//6343 3962//6343 3964//6344 3764//6324

I want to draw the face with 2 triangles which means 2 faces. Right now as you can see this is quad. Each vertex got it own normal.
If I use triangulation and calculate 2 faces, does the normals of each vertex change? Am I need to find my own normals to the new faces?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vertex normals are used in the shader for lighting interpolation purposes, i.e. they represent the normal of the surface at each vertex. If you do not add any vertices, there is no information to add, i.e. the normals stay as they are at the vertices.